# Convert specification to criteria

Tags: spring, spring-data

Is there a way to convert specification into org.hibernate.Criteria?

I have service A which produces specification (I can not modify it) and I have to consume this specification to generate FORWARD_ONLY ScrollableResults, which is not yet supported in specification - is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The Specification interface has a toPredicate method which you can use to

```
 public interface Specification<T> {

  /**
   * Creates a WHERE clause for a query of the referenced entity in form of a {@link Predicate} for the given
   * {@link Root} and {@link CriteriaQuery}.
   * 
   * @param root
   * @param query
   * @return a {@link Predicate}, must not be {@literal null}.
   */
   Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb);
}
```

Then your code will look like this (not tested):

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> query = builder.createQuery(String.class);
Root<DomainObject> domainRoot = query.from(Customer.class);
Predicate predicate = DomainSpec.like('xyz').toPredicate(domainRoot , query, builder);
query = query.where(predicate);
```